# Search with a variable in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to search an array with a variable, which seems to not work because it thinks the variable itself is a value.

```
var variable = "create";

var navViews = {
    "create" : [
        {
            "id"        : "1",
            "name"      : "Create",
            "urlext"    : "stylecreator"
        }
    ]
}
navViews.variable;
```

How do I reach "create" through a variable?

Comment: `navViews[variable]` `navViews.variable;` will check for `"variable"` inside `navViews`

Comment: Are you trying to *search* for a variable here, or just *access* it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get **create** `array`, you can do this in this way:

```
navViews[variable]
```